# Using a For statement to print a string and then set that string as a variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to make a hangman game without copying other examples. I am fully aware I might not be using the most efficient method, but I want to see if there is a way to do this:

I have a string variable called `word`, which is the word being guessed.
Any correctly guessed letter is placed in a list, `rightguesses`.

I am using a `for` loop to print the word, only printing the letters in the `rightguesses` list, and printing a `_` for any letters that are not in the `rightguesses` list.

My problem is that I want to grab the string produced from this `for` loop and assign it to a variable, but I am having trouble figuring out how. Can I use a function and return this value somehow?

So, if the word being guessed is 'python' and `rightguesses` is `['p']`, the string I get is `'p _ _ _ _ _'`. I want to take this string and set it to a variable called `userword` so I can test to see if `userword == word` to determine if the full word has been guessed.

```
word = 'python'
rightguesses = []
wrongguesses = []
guesscount = 0

while guesscount < 10:
    print("Here is the current board:")
    for char in word:
        if char in rightguesses:
            print(char,end='')
        else:
            print("_",end='')
    print("\n")
    print("guess a letter")
    guess = input()
    if guess in word:
        rightguesses.append(guess)
        guesscount += 1
        print(guesscount)
    elif guess not in word and guess not in wrongguesses:
        wrongguesses.append(guess)
        print("Incorrect guess")
        guesscount += 1
    elif guess in wrongguesses or guess in rightguesses:
        print("You've already guessed that")
        continue
```

Comment: _My problem is that I want to grab the string produced from this for loop and assign it to a variable, but I am having trouble figuring out how. Can I use a function and return this value somehow?_ Unless I'm missing something, can't you append the new character(s) to a string inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do that. In your loop that prints a letter or `_`, you can tell if they guessed the whole word if you never print `_`. So set a variable during that loop.

```
while guesscount < 10:
    guessed_right = True
    print("Here is the current board:")
    for char in word:
        if char in rightguesses:
            print(char,end='')
        else:
            print("_",end='')
            guessed_right = False
    print("\n")
    if guessed_right:
        print("You win!")
        break
    print("guess a letter")
    guess = input()
    if guess in word:
        rightguesses.append(guess)
        guesscount += 1
        print(guesscount)
    elif guess not in word and guess not in wrongguesses:
        wrongguesses.append(guess)
        print("Incorrect guess")
        guesscount += 1
    elif guess in wrongguesses or guess in rightguesses:
        print("You've already guessed that")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Above you got an answer on an alternative way of doing this. But if you want to know what getting that variable might look like, here's a way to do it.

Where you had

```py
    for char in word:
        if char in rightguesses:
            print(char, end='')
        else:
            print("_", end='')
    print("\n")
```

you can use

```py
    userword = ""
    for char in word:
        if char in rightguesses:
            userword += char
        else:
            userword += "_"
    print(userword)
```

to, while iterating, build a word in `userword` and call `print()` only once at the end (in your example performance isn't an issue, but calling `print()` for every character may be a performance bottleneck in a more output-heavy program).

Of course, you can then use `"_" in userword` to test if it is complete or not.